# Let $F(x,y,z) = -c(r/||r||^3)$ be the force resulting from the inverse square law...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, vector-analysis, inverse

$c$ is a constant and $r = (x,y,z)$. Show that $\displaystyle f(x,y,z) = \frac{c}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ is a potential function for $F$. What can be concluded from any path from point $A$ to point $B$ in $F$? What can be concluded about a simple closed path in $F$?

Comment: While this is an easy question: what have you done to solve it? Also, isn't that more of a physics.stackexchange question?

Comment: I am attempting to show that f(x,y,z) is conservative, but I cannot figure out where to start..

Comment: You mean you want to show that F is a conservative force. Just check out the wikipedia article about conservatives forces. It'll tell you all you need :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force

Comment: But which of the three methods would I perform in this situation? How do I find the curl of F? And what do I do once I've shown this is conservative?

Comment: As they are all equivalent (it says so in the wiki entry!) choose the one you know how to handle. If you want to know what conservative means: read the article. It's implications are explained there very clearly.

Comment: I know how to use the "Cross-Partial Property of a Conservative Vector Field", however I am unsure how to take dF1/dy of F(x,y,z) = -c(r/||r||^3)..

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an easy question for myself..

Answer (score 1):

A force field $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is conservative if there exists a scalar function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla f=(f_x,f_y,f_z)=F$.  The scalar function $f$ is called a potential function for $F$.  So we only need to check that the given potential function satisfies the equation $\nabla f=F$

Notice that for the given potential function $f$, we have
$$f_x=-\frac{cx}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$

See if you can show that this together with the other partial derivatives give the desired force field $F$.  Remember that $r=(x,y,z)$ so that $||r||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Now, when force fields are conservative, the work done on a particle moving from point $A$ to point $B$ is independent of the path taken from $A$ to $B$.  This can be seen by the line integral analogue of the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$\text{Work done by $F=\nabla f$ in moving a particle from point $A$ to point $B$ along curve $C$}=\\\int_CF\cdot dr=f(B)-f(A)$$
We see that only the endpoints of the curve ($A$ and $B$) determine the work done.

Finally, closed paths in $F$ have the same starting and ending point, that is, $A=B$.  Using the above formula, what does this say about the integral of a conservative force field $F$ on a closed path?

Comment: Okay I believe I got it! However, I do not know what this shows about "any path from point A to point B in F" or "a simple closed path in F

Comment: Hi cppCharizard.  Please see my edit.  Hope this helps.